# BottomSheetBehavior inside nested fragment not working

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, bottom-sheet

My goal is to hide toolbar on scroll up and show on down while tabLayout does not hides but moves up while toolbar hidden.
I have main activity with FrameLayout that handles fragments

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/main_cord"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_supervisor"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:elevation="0dp">
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
            android:textSize="25sp"/>
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragment_loader"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />  </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

fragment_loader loads "mother" fragment where tabLayout and viewPager are initialized

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:elevation="1dp"
    app:tabMode="fixed"
    app:tabGravity="fill" />

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/tabs" /></RelativeLayout>
```

viewPager contains two fragment and one of them actually works... it achieves my goal written above but one which has NestedScrollView with BottomSheetBehavior does not, plus NestedScrollView is hidden and when i scroll up with another fragment (which hasn`t NestedScrollView) and switch back to problematic one, then it shows (short: while toolbar is hidden NestedScrollView is shown)

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:clipToPadding="true"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        app:behavior_peekHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior">
```

so here is my whole code, once i removed BottomSheetBehavior and it worked fine but i need both: hiding toolbar and bottom sheet

Comment: try chaning your nestedScrollview height to wrap_content?

Comment: HourGlass, tried... but sadly it did not work.
there is only one case when it works (in worst solution) when i remove behavior, but i just really need that behavior so...